# Is there an analog of covariance matrix to three dimensional arrays?

Tags: probability-theory, tensors

The variance-covariance matrix of a random vector gives the covariance of the components of the random vector and is a 2-d array.

I'm wondering if there is a natural analog for third moments (and so on to n-d) which is a 3-d array and gives (off-diagonal) something like the covariance between [[one component] and [the conditional covariance of the other two components conditional on the first component]].

Does this 3-d array have a name? Is it important?

Comment: Do you mean [mixed moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Mixed_moments) ? In particular, coskewness, cokurtosis ?

Comment: Yes I think that's what I had in mind. I'm surprised I haven't heard more about those.